# R reticulate package not finding Python win32com module

Tags: python, r, win32com, reticulate

I'm trying to use `reticulate` in R to access Python's `win32com` (in order to read password-protected Excel documents), but am failing at the first hurdle. Although my code works fine in Python, when trying to use it in `reticulate`, the `win32com` module cannot be found.

As an example:

```
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate-test")
py_install(envname = "r-reticulate-test", packages = "pywin32")
win32 = import("win32com.client")
```

Results in:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the following solved the issue:

```
library(reticulate)
install.packages("Rcpp")
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate-test")
py_install("pypiwin32", pip = T, envname = "r-reticulate-test")
win32 <- import("win32com.client")
```

Comment: For explanation, `win32com` is only available for Python on Windows environments (not Mac/Linux or other OSes). Hence, your solution to run a Python Windows vritualenv is required.